# when I export dataframe to excel I got just part of columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have nested dictionary which I try to export to excel
I have code which generate correct dataframe, the idea is to generate it in excel, but I get in excel only part of the columns, what I am doing wrong

```
user_ids = []
frames = []

for user_id, d in res_duplicate.items():
    for item in d:
        user_ids.append(user_id)
        frames.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index'))

df = pd.concat(frames, keys=user_ids)
print (df)
df.to_excel('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dict1.xlsx', index = False, header=False)
```

when I print dataframe I got

[image]

but in excel I have just columns time and docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 2 columns are `MultiIndex`, so if use `index=False` is not written to excel. Possible solution is remove it:

```
df = pd.concat(frames, keys=user_ids)
df.to_excel('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dict1.xlsx', header=False)
```

Or convert `MultiIndex` to columns, then default RangeIndex is by `index=False` omitted:

```
df = pd.concat(frames, keys=user_ids).reset_index()
df.to_excel('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dict1.xlsx',index = False,  header=False)
```